# Android fire-base OTP not verifying

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I made an application to read OTP and login with mobile number,it is like in first screen user have to enter mobile number and continue at the time otp will send to the user and it goes to second activity .here user will enter otp , that otp will go to the first activity, at the end my app not verifying the otp ,please help me

```
 public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText phonetextview;
String phone_number;
FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
private  String verificationCode;
    private String mVerificationId;


PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
private static final String TAG ="MainActivity";
String verificationId;
String code;
//    final PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


   //






    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String otp = intent.getStringExtra("otp");

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),otp,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();







    //getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);


    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"hoooooooooo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);



        }

        private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {


            System.exit(0);

        }


        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence) e,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

            }

        }


        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                               PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {



            Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);

            mVerificationId = verificationId;
            mResendToken = token;

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Otp.class);
            startActivity(i);


           // View v = (View) findViewById(R.id.phonetextview);
            //((ViewManager)v.getParent()).removeView(v);
            //View vv = (View) findViewById(R.id.cardView);
            //((ViewManager)vv.getParent()).removeView(vv);







        }



    };

    CardView card_view = findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    card_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {






            phonetextview =findViewById(R.id.phonetextview);
            phone_number = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(phonetextview.getText().toString());

            send();



            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), phone_number,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();



        }


    });

}

private void send() {

    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
           "+91"+phone_number,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks);             // ForceResendingToken from callbacks


}
    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"hoooooooooo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                            // [START_EXCLUDE]

                            // [END_EXCLUDE]
                        } else {
                            // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                // The verification code entered was invalid
                                // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                                //mVerificationField.setError("Invalid code.");
                                // [END_EXCLUDE]
                            }
                            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                            // Update UI
                          //  updateUI(STATE_SIGNIN_FAILED);
                            // [END_EXCLUDE]
                        }
                    }
                });
    }


}
```

and this is my otp typing activity

```
 public class Otp extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp);





    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {



            EditText fd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
            String value= fd.getText().toString();
  //        int finalValue=Integer.parseInt(value);

            final EditText sd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
            String value1= sd.getText().toString();
            // int finalValue1=Integer.parseInt(value1);

            EditText td = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et3);
            String value2= td.getText().toString();
            // int finalValue2=Integer.parseInt(value2);

            EditText fod = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et4);
            String value3= fod.getText().toString();
            //int finalValue3=Integer.parseInt(value3);

            EditText fid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et5);
            String value4= fid.getText().toString();
            //int finalValue4=Integer.parseInt(value4);

            EditText sid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et6);
            String value5= sid.getText().toString();
            //int finalValue5=Integer.parseInt(value5);




            final String otp = value + value1+value2+value3+value4+value5;



            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("otp", otp);
            startActivity(intent);


        finish();





        }
    });


}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is not getting OTP, then the solution is to Add SHA-1 fingerprint to your Firebase Project. This is Common Problem for so many of not getting OTP from Firebase

Comment: i am getting otp but its not verifying ,  without SHA-1 fingerprint otp wont come , i have error in my code

Comment: Try this code [link](https://github.com/cyberworldtechnologies/PhoneOTPAuthentication)